# Singly Linked List with special methods in python, stuck

Tags: python, linked-list, complexity-theory, nodes, singly-linked-list

A singly linked list with two classes, Node and LinkedList, is easy enough to implement. however my issue is when it comes to a singly linked list with only first node access (No stored length, No last node access, and without the use of dummy nodes). The special methods I can't wrap my head around or find much about online are similar to pythons built-in list operations with O(1) complexity, such as follows:

```
aa = LinkedList()  --  creates empty list
aa.first()  --  similar to aa[0]
aa.rest()  --  similar to aa[1:]
aa.cons(item)  --  similar to aa[item:]
[item] + aa  --  similar to aa.insert(0, item)
```

Any sort of lead, help, guidance would be greatly appreciated. For some reason I just cant interpret pythons built-in list operators into my own methods in LinkedList without having dummy nodes or stored length and an iterator. Looking at it it just seems like I'm so close yet nothing I do or find seems to help. Thank you.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

  def getData(self):
    return self.data

  def getNext(self):
    return self.next

  def setData(self, newdata):
    self.data = newdata

  def setNext(self, newnext):
    self.next = newnext

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.data)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "Node(%s, %s)" % (repr(self.data), repr(self.next))

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.data == other.data and self.next == other.next

class myList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.first = Node()

  def add(self, data):
    newNode = Node() # create a new node
    newNode.data = data
    newNode.next = self.first # link the new node to the 'previous' node.
    self.first = newNode #  set the current node to the new one

  def first(self):
    return self.first.data


  def __repr__(self):
    plist = []
    for i in self:
        plist.append(i)
    return "LinkedList(%s)" % str(plist)
```

Comment: Please post your current code, even if it isn't fully functional.

Comment: Like I said I I don't know what I'm doing at this point I just need a lead. But heres the complete Node class and basic LinkedList class

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you in a class that's studying encapsulation and OO programming?  In Python, it's a bit odd to do something like `node.setData(5)` when you can just normally do `node.data = 5`.  You can also use decorators to wrap variables if you need to control access to them.

Comment: Why not use collections.deque?

Comment: Thats exactly it. We're taking the long road, and all the resources we have doesn't really help with this small program. Just stuck right here and trying to find that small push

Comment: I think @sgusc found the most important problem for you: you have a method function named `first` and a member variable named `first`.  One will hide the other; rename one of them.  But by the way, I recommend always declaring your classes to inherit from `object` so that you always have the full power of inheritance when writing Python programs.  for example: `class Node(object):`

Comment: I think you've got `cons` wrong. It should add `item` to the beginning of the list, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I think the basic hint I can give is that if you're during Linked List-based operations, it's going to involve a lot of iteration.  Using stuff like `aa.cons(item)` is going to be inefficient and based on iteration because unlike an array-based list, you can't jump to an item at a particular index.

For the following examples, I'm going to assume your `LinkedList` class has a variable called `first` that points to the first item in the list and each `Node` has a variable called `next` that points to the next item in the list and a variable called `data` that holds the data at that node.

For `aa.first()`, that should be easy since you already have a variable `head` pointing to the first item.  Just return that.

For the other methods, you'll need iteration.  This is an example of how you might loop through and print out the list.

```
current = list.first
while current is not None:
    print current.data
    current = current.next
```

For `aa.rest()`, you'll have to skip the first item and then loop through the rest of the list.  To take a step in the list, you essentially keep track of your current location and iterate.  To return list[1:], I imagine the easiest thing to do is make a new list and then  iterate, adding all the items from 1 to the end.

`aa.rest()` is really just a special case of `aa.cons(item)`.  You iterate through the list until your current pointer reaches `item` and then make a new list containing everything from after that.

You don't necessarily have to make new lists to return from `rest()` and `cons(...)`, it just depends on how you want to implement it.  I'll leave insert for you to think about.

With a `LinkedList` that only has a pointer to the `head`, you're not going to get O(1) for anything other than adding to the front of the list or accessing the first item, everything else is going to be approximately O(N).

I hope that helps a bit!

Comment: it seems so easy, but when I write up the code i get attribute and type errors. "Node" isn't callable when trying to return aa.first() etc

Comment: Took me a minute to spot that one.  I think your problem is that you have a variable named `first` and a method named `first()` in your `LinkedList`.  Try naming the method something different.  The problem is that the method `first` gets created first, then you overwrite it with the variable `first` in `__init__`, so when you go to do `aa.first()`, it's trying to call the first node in the list as a method.

Comment: @user1337598, I'm not sure what you mean about "Node" isn't callable.  When you call `Node()` Python creates a new instance for you.  That isn't something you need for `aa.first()`, so I'm not sure why you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

@sgusc found the one really big problem with what you have so far: naming a function `first` and naming a data attribute `first` as well.  The latter winds up overriding the former (because the function is actually in the `class` rather than the instance).

Fixing this gives something that is close to working.  I simplified a few things, added a little test driver, and added an `__iter__` that uses a generator to yield each node's data in turn, so that `for i in self` (in `myList.__repr__`) can work.  Diff:

```
--- a/user1337598.py
+++ b/user1337598.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-class Node:
+class Node(object):
   def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
     self.data = data
     self.next = next
@@ -19,27 +19,36 @@ class Node:
     return str(self.data)

   def __repr__(self):
-    return "Node(%s, %s)" % (repr(self.data), repr(self.next))
+    return "Node(%r, %r)" % (self.data, self.next)

   def __eq__(self, other):
     return self.data == other.data and self.next == other.next

-class myList:
+class myList(object):
   def __init__(self):
-    self.first = Node()
+    self.first = None

   def add(self, data):
-    newNode = Node() # create a new node
-    newNode.data = data
-    newNode.next = self.first # link the new node to the 'previous' node.
+    newNode = Node(data, self.first) # create a new node
     self.first = newNode #  set the current node to the new one

-  def first(self):
+  def getFirst(self):
     return self.first.data

+  def __iter__(self):
+      node = self.first
+      while node is not None:
+          yield node.data
+          node = node.next

   def __repr__(self):
     plist = []
     for i in self:
         plist.append(i)
     return "LinkedList(%s)" % str(plist)
+
+if __name__ == '__main__':
+    lst = myList()
+    lst.add(1)
+    lst.add(2)
+    print repr(lst)
```

Note that `repr` uses the name `LinkedList` even though the class name is `myList`.  I usually write my `repr` functions to use `self.__class__.__name__`, e.g.:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '%s(%r, %r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.item1, self.item2)
```

which also allows a base-class `__repr__` to work for derived classes (sometimes with a little assistance from the derived-class).